# Flashing a soft bricked Blu Life One XL

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking, twrp

Recently I tried to root my phone using [KingoRoot](https://www.kingoapp.com/). The result was a [BLU Life One XL](http://www.gsmarena.com/blu_life_one_xl-6929.php) that wouldn't load past the BLU logo.

The first thing I tried, was going into Recovery Mode and clearing cache and reloading, then clearing user data and reloading. Neither worked. After some research, it looks like I'll need to flash stock or some other compatible ROM to my phone.

As such, I downloaded a ROM from the [XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/), stuck it on my miniSD card, and tried to install it through the recovery mode menu. However, the result was an error dealing with signature verification failed and installation aborted. To get past this, apparently I need [TWRP](https://twrp.me/about/), [CWM](http://www.clockworkmod.com/), or some other custom recovery where I can turn of signature verification. I've tried adding these from the SD card both as zip and Bootable SD card, but neither worked. I can't even get to the bootloader since if I choose the reboot to bootloader option from the Android system recovery, it just gets stuck at the BLU loading screen.

So, how can I flash a ROM to my phone without being able to load past recovery screen? I think if I can only get custom recovery on my phone it should work, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: On what platform is your device: Qualcomm or Mediatek ? Because the processes are different

Comment: @esQmo Qualcomm